# Adding to bidirectional ManyToMany collection retrieves all entries already in relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have User entity mapped by users in UserGroup entity

**USER.java**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups;

public void addGroup(UserGroup userGroup){
this.userGroups.add(userGroup);
userGroup.addUser(this);
}
```

**UserGroup.java**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "group_users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<User> users;

public void addUser(User user) {
   this.users.add(user);
}
```

I have a method to add Group to User in UserService:

```
@Transactional
public void addGroupsToUser(UserAddGroupsCommand userAddGroupsCommand, String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user != null) {
        List<UserGroup> userGroupList = userGroupRepository.findAllById(userAddGroupsCommand.getId());
        for (UserGroup userGroup : userGroupList) {
            user.addGroup(userGroup);
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I iterate through groups and add user to each group, for some reason Hibernate selects All users in that group (from join table).

```
Hibernate: 
select
    users0_.group_id as group_id1_3_1_,
    users0_.user_id as user_id2_3_1_,
    user1_.id as id1_7_0_,
    user1_.email as email2_7_0_,
    user1_.firstname as firstnam3_7_0_,
    user1_.is_admin as is_admin4_7_0_,
    user1_.lastname as lastname5_7_0_,
    user1_.password as password6_7_0_,
    user1_.username as username7_7_0_ 
from
    group_users users0_ 
inner join
    user user1_ 
        on users0_.user_id=user1_.id 
where
    users0_.group_id in (
        select
            usergroup0_.id 
        from
            user_group usergroup0_ 
        where
            usergroup0_.id in (
                ? , ?
            )
    )
```

How to avoid that? Any option to do avoid this without writing own query, just with annotations and JPA Repository methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding group there are 2 selects:

for fetching groups in user calling `user.getUserGroups().add(group)`

```
select usergroups0_.user_id as user_id2_0_0_, usergroups0_.group_id as group_id1_0_0_, usergroup1_.id as id1_8_1_ 
from group_users usergroups0_ 
inner join UserGroup usergroup1_ on usergroups0_.group_id=usergroup1_.id 
where usergroups0_.user_id=?
```

for fetching users in group calling `group.addUser(user)`

```
select users0_.group_id as group_id1_0_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id2_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_7_1_ 
from group_users users0_ 
inner join User user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id 
where users0_.group_id=?
```

users field needs to be initialized, either way you load it lazy or eagerly.

Comment: Yes, but why Hibernate selects all users from every group I want to add that user to. I mean why not just insert user_id group_id into join table group_users instead of selecting all entries from group_users that have no relation to the user I try to insert?

Comment: Because you are accessing it. Hibernate does not know what do you want to do with that collection. This is how it works. You can still do a native SQL insert to that table if you want. JPA is not good to use if you want to have full control over queries.

Comment: Understand now. But is Entity Graph solution for this?

Comment: No. If a fetch graph is used, only the attributes specified by the entity graph will be treated as FetchType.EAGER

Comment: Thank you, Peter. So what would be you suggestion on this? Should I write Query? As far as I know I can not insert entries into join table.

Comment: Peter. Sure I will. I just did not understand the part with group.addUser(user). I see that when I add user to group it fetch all users in that group. My user holds like 50+ groups which has 1000+ users each and every time it fetches all users from every group I add user to. Is it standard behavior that hibernate selects all data from join table when actually I just need to have one entry inserted? The reason I ask is that when I add multiple group to user I can see significant lag in execution and checking console show me that delay comes because hibernate selects all users from all groups.

Comment: Solution depends on use case. Create a new question for it. I can answer it there. Consider also marking as correct your previous questions. Stackoverflow is driven by this.